# Python Selenium. Поставить лайк под видео на ютубе

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

**Пытаюсь реализовать, но возникает исключение:**

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element button id="button" class="style-scope yt-icon-button" could not be scrolled into view

**Мой код:**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# <здесь код для загрузки куков (чтоб быть залогиненым на ютуб)> 
# не буду его сюда вставлять - он работает  

video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video_id>'
driver.get(video_url)
# подождать подольше, чтоб наверняка загрузился
sleep(12)  

# возможно тут я ошибся и он найдёт не кнопку лайка, а что то другое
xpath = '//button[@id="button"]'
like_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

like_button.click()
```

**Просьба написать работающий код.**

Я облазил форумы, где обсуждались похожие проблемы и перепробовал много вариантов, например перед кликом сделать прокрутку к элементу, чтобы он был виден, но это не помогло.

```
driver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform();
# или так
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя xpath не туда смотрит, воспользуйся этим: `(//div[@id="top-level-buttons"]//a)[1]//button`
Так же для удобства написания xpath, можешь установить расширение в хроме "XPath Helper"